# GKE Multiple PersistentVolumeClaims on one Filestore

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-filestore

I need help understanding my Google Filestore issue.

I created a Filestore instance with BASIC_HDD and 1TB storage. In GKE, I provisioned a PersistentVolume as following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: my-fileshare
spec:
 capacity:
   storage: 1T
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 nfs:
   path: /fileshare
   server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

My question is, can I create multiple PersistentVolumeClaims from this 1TB? Like multiple PVCs using i.e. 100GB each?

Answer (score 2):

I've tested it myself now.

PV's and PVC's have a **1:1 relationship**. Every PersistentVolume can carry *exactly* one PersistentVolumeClaim.

**But** you can create multiple PersistentVolumes! For example, if you want to split your `1TB` (the minimum for a HDD instance) into 5 equal parts, you can just create 5 PersistentVolumes with different names that use the same fileshare. Just take the script from my question, change the name and scale the size down to `200G`. Tada, you have split up your Filestore instance to 5 PersistentVolumes and can now use it for different purposes.